CSS, vertical align on text without adding space to line height
100ᱸ000
There is a character I use as thousand separator. Its width is too large so i set its font-size specifically to 10px obtaining this:

I want to align the 10px version vertically to the top of the line like in 100ᱸ000 but without it taking space in the line height of the upper and lower line.
I tried
gah {
font-size: 10px;
vertical-align: super;
}

But it adds space in the upper line
-
Also tried this lacking alternative (without setting font-size) but failed anyway, by controlling the excessive space of the character:
gah {
letter-spacing: -1px;
}
gah:before {
content: "\80";
}

u0080 is not recognized(x in a box unicode appears) by my mobile device somehow (2018 phone) so the second attempt failed.
What I want:
A way to make the thousand separator not add space in the upper line when vertically aligned to the top. The solution must not add width to the character.
Edit: better code.
the string is 100ᱸ000
i modified it to 100<gaf>ᱸ</gaf>000 using the css above, that is all.

please share full code of html and CSS for better understanding

@MushfiqurRahman  100<gah>ᱸ</gah>000

Please put code in the question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Just change the line height to eliminate any additional "height" in the seperator glyph. Then vertical-align to the top.


p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.seperator {
  line-height: .0;
  background: lightblue;
  /* background for demo only - for visibility */
  vertical-align: text-top;
  display: inline-block;
  /* hides background */
}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum possimus <span>100<span class="seperator">.</span>000</span> molestias eligendi aliquam veniam officiis impedit iusto similique odit culpa.</p>




You forgot to add the smaller font size to separator. Also it needs super instead of top-text. It works now thanks for the answer.
